# HTMLElement as union discriminated by tagName

Tags: typescript, types, discriminated-union

I'd like TypeScript to know that when I switch on an element's `tagName` and the case is, for example, 'input', then the element in the case's code is an input element. I know in principle this is possible using discriminated unions, but apparently neither `Element` nor `HTMLElement` types are discriminated unions, so the following code fails:

```
function foo(e : HTMLElement) {
    switch(e.tagName) {
        case 'input':
            e.value = '123'; // Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
            break;
        case 'a':
            e.href = 'hi'; // Property 'href' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
            break;
    }
}
```

So as a quick workaround I can do this:

```
interface TaggedLink extends HTMLLinkElement { 
    tagName: 'a'
}

interface TaggedInput extends HTMLInputElement {
    tagName: 'input'
}

type TaggedHTMLElement = TaggedLink | TaggedInput;

function foo(e : TaggedHTMLElement) {
    switch(e.tagName) {
        case 'input':
            e.value = '123'; // Good
            break;
        case 'a':
            e.href = 'hi'; // Good
            break;
    }
}
```

That works, but now everyone calling `foo` will have to cast the argument to `TaggedHTMLElement`.

So I wonder if TypeScript already comes with an element-as-a-discriminated-union type that I can directly use as the type of foo's argument that works out of the box, or if there's a better way to do what I'm trying to. I know there's a type called `HTMLElementTagNameMap` which seems like it could be useful, but I think I'd need to be able to re-define `HTMLElement` (something like `interface HTMLElement extends actual HTMLElement`), and some way to loop through all types in `HTMLElementTagNameMap` to generate types like the ones I defined above and then union them all. But it doesn't seem that any of these things are possible.

Comment: Why don't you keep the arg type as `HTMLElement` and cast it to `TaggedHTMLElement` internally, e.g. within the switch condition in `foo`?

Answer (score 1):

`HTMLElement` and `Element` already has `tagName` property, and it is **readonly** and just a `string`.

If you want to exactly know which element is, you have to make runtime check for element instance.

```
function foo(e : HTMLLinkElement | HTMLInputElement) {
  if (e instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
    e.value = '123';
  }
  else if (e instanceof HTMLLinkElement) {
    e.href = 'hi';
  }
}


const el = document.querySelector<HTMLLinkElement>("a")

if (el) {
  foo(el)
}
``
```